# Ban IP Ranges php

Tags: php, ip

I found this code:

```
<?php               
    $ban_ip_range = array('10.49.*.*');
    $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if(!empty($ban_ip_range)) {
        foreach($ban_ip_range as $range) {
            $range = str_replace('*','(.*)', $range);

            if(preg_match('/'.$range.'/', $user_ip)) {
                echo "NO access";
            }
            else {
                echo 'you have access'; 
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

This code is completely functional and working, the thing is that I want to add more than one range so I did this:

```
$ban_ip_range = array('10.49.*.*','10.65.*.*');
```

But this one didn't work , it goes throught the two parts of the conditional and it shows :

```
"NO accessyou have access"
```

Any way of fixxing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a flag, toggle it when you find a match, evaluate it after the loop.

```
$ban_ip_range = array('10.49.*.*','10.65.*.*');
$user_ip = '10.65.1.2'; //$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$access = true;

if(!empty($ban_ip_range)) {
    foreach($ban_ip_range as $range) {
        $range = str_replace('*','(.*)', $range);

        if(preg_match('/'.$range.'/', $user_ip)) {
            $access = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if($access) {
    echo 'you have access'; 
} else {
    echo 'NO access';
}
```